# Question about Perfect Mapping in Topology

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

Given two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$, we define the map $f$ from $X$ to $Y$ as perfect map if $f$ is continuous, surjective, closed, and proper map (or that inverse image of each point in $Y$ is compact in $X$).

My question is that is the requirement of surjectivity really needed?  I mean even if a function is not surjective, the inverse image of unmapped point $y$ in $Y$ is empty set, which is compact.  So why would surjectivity required as a definition?

Answer (score 1):

The point of requiring it to be surjective is that we typically want to use it and properties of $X$ to tell us something about $Y$, not just about $f[X]$. For instance, perfect maps preserve regularity, local compactness, and second countability. They are also quotient maps, so surjectivity means that $Y$ is a quotient of $X$.

Comment: What is surjectivity removed?  Would that still be acceptable in terms of the rest of definition ?

Comment: @Phoenix13 It sort of would, it forces $f[X]$ to be closed in $Y$, clearly, but it defeats the purpose of *why* we study perfect maps in the first place. In practice/"real life" (in as far as maths can be real life) you always want onto perfect maps. And it's all one encounters, really. I concur with Brian on this.

Comment: So the whole point of surjectivity is to make sure the image of X captures the whole Y.   I can see bijectiviry would be nicer!